# How to locate outliner

Tags: modeling

I suddenly lost my outliner! (Where all the items are listed)! how to locate it? or get it back?
I was roaming around but its gone!

please help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://youtu.be/8XyIYRW_2xk?t=63

Comment: No, I lost it. :'( I wish there were some default workspace to which I can go back if I mess up the  interface. it's just gone! I restarted. all the work I have done so love gone! I am crying now.

Comment: If you saved the file nothing is lost.

Comment: I didn't save. anyway I practiced again. My gain.

Comment: Next time just push the + button on the right of the workspaces names, select "Layout": it will create  a new default workspace.

Comment: And you can go to the menu "File" > recover > autosave to recover last files, even if not saved yet.

Comment: Thank you so much! @joshsanfelici